# Shorten the python if-statement syntax

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

Is it possible to shorten the if statements below ?

```
if r < 0: r = 0
elif r > 255: r = 255
if g < 0: g = 0  
elif g > 255: g = 255
if b < 0: b = 0
elif b > 255: b = 255
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you call as clamping. Create a clamp function as below:

```
def clamp(n, smallest, largest): 
    return max(smallest, min(n, largest))
```

Now you can call it on your variables as

```
r = clamp(r, 0, 255)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min` and `max`.

```
r = min(max(r, 0), 255)
```

The inner expression makes sure `r` is at least 0. The outer expression makes sure it's no more than 255.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question on shorting the if statement code you provided and not providing an alternative solution to getting the same result as your if statement.

```
def rgb_8bit_trunc(r,g,b):

    print("Input: r:{}, g:{}, b:{}".format(r,g,b))

    r = 0 if r < 0 else r if r < 255 else 255
    g = 0 if g < 0 else g if g < 255 else 255
    b = 0 if b < 0 else b if b < 255 else 255

    print("Output: r:{}, g:{}, b:{}".format(r,g,b))

rgb_8bit_trunc(256,256,256)
rgb_8bit_trunc(-1,-1,-1)
```

Each ternary conditional operator is equivalent to the if statement code below where 'value' may be any of your RGB variables.

```
if value < 255:
    if value < 0:
        value = 0
    else:
        value
else:
    value = 255
```